# is there an XML equivalent of Json.reads[Foo] and Json.writes[Foo] in the Play Framework

Tags: xml, json, scala, playframework-2.0

In the Play Framework on Scala, setting up json serialization is as simple as adding

```
implicit val siteReads = Json.reads[Foo]
implicit val siteWrites = Json.writes[Foo]
```

to the Foo object in your model. Is there an equivalently easy way to do this for XML?

Comment: [scalaxb](http://scalaxb.org/) provides similar type class-based serialization for XML, but works in the opposite direction—you provide the schema and it generates the model code and type class instances. I don't know of an XML equivalent for Inception (which is what you're using here).

Comment: There is nothing in Play that offers this functionality, we have been using plain old projection functions from the Scala library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent API for Xml yet.

But the good news is that they are working on that.
http://jto.github.io/articles/play_new_validation_api/
and
http://mandubian.com/2014/01/31/play-rules-shapeless/